# get latest file from a directory

Tags: bash

In a bash script I have the following command to get the latest backup file from a specific directory:

```
find /mnt/synology/bk/ -maxdepth 1 -name 'bk-*' -mmin -60 -print0 | xargs -0 ls -1 -t 2>/dev/null | head -n 1
```

If there is no file found, the command will return a file in the current directory... (where the command is executed)

Is a way to return an empty output if no file matched ?

Thx

Comment: Can't you just check the output starts with `/mnt/synology/bk/`?

Comment: @choroba the find ... will return an empty output if nothing match

Comment: See the `-r` option of GNU `xargs`

Comment: @Paul: Sure, and the output of `head` won't start with `/mnt/synology/bk/`. It's easy to check that, but using `-r` is probably even easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try -r option to xargs

```
-r, --no-run-if-empty
               If the standard input does not contain any nonblanks, do not run the command.  Normally, the command is run once even if there is no input.  This option is a GNU extension.
```

Answer (score 0):

Except in some BSDs, `xargs cmd` still runs `cmd` once with no argument when the input is empty. GNU `xargs` (the implementation that also introduced `-0`) has a `-r` option (now also supported by a few other implementations) to avoid that.

Now, there  a few other problems with your approach:

- if there's a large number of files, `xargs` would run `ls -t` several times, so you would not get the latest file, just the latest of the first batch
- you're not passing the `-d` option to `ls` which means that if any of those files are of type *directory*, their content will be listed.
- you're using `-print0`/`xargs -0` which allows handling of arbitrary file names, but that's broken when you use `ls -t` which no longer outputs the list of files NUL-delimited.

Here, you could use `zsh` where it becomes trivial:

```
newest=(/mnt/synology/bk/bk-*(Nmh-1om[1]))
if (($#newest)); then
  printf 'Newest: %s\n' $newest
else
  echo none found
fi
```

Or with GNU `find` (which you're probably using as `-maxdepth` and `-mmin` are GNU extensions) and `sort`/`cut`/`head` implementations the support NUL characters in their input:

```
find /mnt/synology/bk -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 \
                      -name 'bk-*' -mmin -60 -printf '%T@/%p\0' |
  tr '\n\0' '\0\n' |
  sort -rn |
  cut -d/ -f2- |
  head -n1 |
  tr '\0' '\n'
```

(note however that contrary to `zsh`, `find` could fail to find some `bk-*` files if the part after `bk-` contains sequences of bytes that don't form valid characters).